# Karma unit test -Calling controller's function but not able to inject Service Object

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-mocha

1. If my unit test is calling function which is in controller and that function is having a service call to fetch the details. Will it call service(StationService)?
2. My Karma unit test is not able to inject StationService and not able to call service.

My Code.

```
/// controller


var policyControllers = angular.module('policyControllers', []);
policyControllers.controller('StationListController', ['$translate', '$scope','$rootScope','$state', 'StationService', 'StationListExportService', function ($translate, $scope, $rootScope, $state, StationService, StationListExportService) {
...
$scope.getFilterDetails = function(StationService, filterDetails ){

  StationService.get(filterDetails).$promise.then(function (filteredDetails) {
        console.log(" Web services Result - ", JSON.stringify(filteredDetails));            
    },function(error) {
        console.log(" Error ");
    });
  };


///Service  

var policyServices = angular.module('policyServices', ['ngResource']);
policyServices.factory('StationService', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource(policyConfig.mock? 'modules/policymanager/services/mock/stations.json': 'http://10.132.240.25:7640/policy/api/v1/stationpolicy/stations',{},{
    get:{method: 'POST',isArray: false, url:'modules/policymanager/services/mock/stations.json'}
  });
}]);



/// Unit test
describe('station filter', function(){

  var scope;
  var ctrl;
  var translate, scope, rootScope, state;
  var StationService, StationListExportService;

  beforeEach(module('policyServices'));
  beforeEach(module('policyControllers'));



  beforeEach(inject(function(_StationService_, _StationListExportService_, $rootScope, $controller, $translate, $state) {

    StationService = _StationService_;
    StationListExportService = _StationListExportService_;
    translate = $translate;
    rootScope = $rootScope;
    state = $state;
    scope = $rootScope.$new();
    ctrl = $controller('StationListController', {$scope: scope});

  }));




  it('Stations Inject test case', inject(['StationService',function(StationService){

      var data = {"recency":"","countries":[],"policies":[],"stations":[{"stationName":"Test"}],"status":"ready","regions":[]};

    scope.getFilterDetails(StationService, data);

  ///  Getting StationService is undifiened 

  }]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using only one application say policyServices and use the same to define the controller as well. In addition to it try defining your service before you use them in your controller.

```
var policyServices = angular.module('policyServices', ['ngResource']);
policyServices.factory('StationService', ['$resource', function($resource) 
{
  return $resource(policyConfig.mock? 'modules/policymanager/services/mock/stations.json': 'http://10.132.240.25:7640/policy/api/v1/stationpolicy/stations',{},{
  get:{method: 'POST',isArray: false, url:'modules/policymanager/services/mock/stations.json'}
  });
}]);

policyServices.controller('StationListController', ['$translate', '$scope','$rootScope','$state', 'StationService', 'StationListExportService', function ($translate, $scope, $rootScope, $state, StationService, StationListExportService) {
...
 $scope.getFilterDetails = function(StationService, filterDetails ){

  StationService.get(filterDetails).$promise.then(function (filteredDetails) {
    console.log(" Web services Result - ", JSON.stringify(filteredDetails));            
},function(error) {
    console.log(" Error ");
});
```

};